# grouping the record basis of different criteria

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have table like bellow how to write a workable code.

```
code    type    date        amount
2001    Advance 01/01/2015  200 
3001    Advance 02/05/2015  0   
2001    Balance 12/30/2015  500 
3001    Balance 05/05/2015  200 
3002    Advance 01/03/2015  100
```

I need to select only the item with it's balance received and total amount also need to show in full like:All the itemcode has one advance and one balance. But I need to retrieve only both records exist otherwise advance and balance are received. if both records are there then it should show 'closed'

```
code    type    date        amount
2001    Closed  12/30/2015  700
3001    closed  05/05/2015  200
```

Comment: not able to get your question,please elaborate

Comment: this table is a log file, the itemcode 2001 on 1/1/2015 received its advance and on 12/30/2015 received balance amount then total is 700 and I will count or take the date only those item it's balance received. Total amount is advance+balance and date is balance received date

Comment: Take a quick look at the [SO help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  They contain a handy guide to asking questions in a format that is more likely to attract an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a flag sort of thing to do get this, you may try the below query

select code,'closed',amt
from (SELECT CODE,sum(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Advance' then 1 when type = 'Balance' then 2 end) flg,
sum(amt) amt
FROM TRY
group by code) where flg = 3;

Comment: Can you verify the code again it showing some error